# How to use DECLARE in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, ssms, declare, azure-synapse

I am creating a stored procedure that will create a new row in a table once the record is new and update the existing record if the record is present in the table.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [procedurename]
    (@UserName [varchar](50),
     @UserEmail [varchar](50),
     @Role [varchar](30),
     @Status [varchar](30),
     @CreationDate [Date])
AS
    DECLARE @countRec INT

    SELECT @countRec = COUNT(*) 
    FROM [Synapse].[tablename] 
    WHERE [UserName] = @Username

BEGIN
    IF (@countRec = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Synapse].[tablename] ([UserName], [UserEmail], [Role], [Status], [CreationDate])
        VALUES (@Username, @UserEmail, @Role, @Status, @CreationDate)
    END
    ELSE (@countRec > 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Synapse].[tablename]
        SET [Role] = @Role, 
            [Status] = @Status, 
            [CreationDate] = @CreationDate 
        WHERE [UserName] = @Username

        INSERT INTO [Synapse].[tablename]
    END
```

And I am getting the following error:

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
> Parse error at line: 39, column: 7: Incorrect syntax near '@countRec'.

I am not sure why it is pointing at the countRec variable. I was able to use a similar set-up without any issues. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Kind regards,

Rutger

Comment: Replace ELSE (@countRec>0)  with simple ELSE

Comment: The first error I get isn't on Line 8, it's on line 35: `ELSE (@countRec>0)`. If you want a boolean expression for your `ELSE` it needs to be `ELSE IF` not just `ELSE`.

Comment: If I use ELSE I get the following (Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Parse error at line: 46, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'END'.)

Comment: If I use ELSE IF (@countRec>0) I get the following error: Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Parse error at line: 46, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Comment: Well, count your `BEGIN` and `END`s - they should be equal. You appear to have a bonus one above your `IF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of syntax errors - mostly: you need to start your proedure with a `BEGIN` before doing any declarations or selects - and you're missing an `END` at the end.

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [procedurename]
    (@UserName [varchar](50),
     @UserEmail [varchar](50),
     @Role [varchar](30),
     @Status [varchar](30),
     @CreationDate [Date])
AS
BEGIN    -- put the "BEGIN" before you start declaring and selecting stuff
    DECLARE @countRec INT

    SELECT @countRec = COUNT(*) 
    FROM [Synapse].[tablename] 
    WHERE [UserName] = @Username

    IF (@countRec = 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Synapse].[tablename] ([UserName], [UserEmail], [Role], [Status], [CreationDate])
        VALUES (@Username, @UserEmail, @Role, @Status, @CreationDate)
    END
    -- either you have just an "ELSE" here - or if you want to 
    -- check another conditions, you need to use "ELSE IF ....."
    ELSE IF (@countRec > 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Synapse].[tablename]
        SET [Role] = @Role, 
            [Status] = @Status, 
            [CreationDate] = @CreationDate 
        WHERE [UserName] = @Username
    END
END   -- this was missing
```

Comment: `BEGIN`/`END` around the entire procedure body is [optional in T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax). The end of the procedure is delimited by the end of the batch in that case.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: ok - but the OP had a `BEGIN` after the initial declare and selct - but not `END` for that `BEGIN` ...

Comment: @marc_s Thank you! It worked. Got lost in all the Begins and Ends...